# Rendering correct data from json api using ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using openweathermap api to get the weather of a place but when I write the name of a place, generally it doesn't render the weather of the right place. But if I add one or two spaces after the place, it renders the weather of the correction place.

I'm using ReactJS.

Can anyone explain me what I'm doing wrong. I'm new to ReactJS.

Here is the demo: http://ghoshnirmalya.github.io/WeatherGrid

Here is the javascript file: https://github.com/ghoshnirmalya/WeatherGrid/blob/master/app/weather-grid/weather-grid.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had a look at the demo, but it (still) does not work.
This is the output I get:
[image]

Looks like your code needs 2 fixes:

1. You call `setState()` twice in the same function, and you have other code after `setState()`. Since setting state causes re-render, you should a) only call it once inside a block/ function and b) call it only at the end of the block/ function.
2. Better to put the async call and the handling of the response in different functions.

So I would change code as follows:

```
...
function getWeatherRequestListener( e ) {
  weatherData                             = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
  weatherDataCityName                     = weatherData.city.name;
  ...
  weatherDataCityHumidity                 = weatherData.list[0].humidity;

  this.setState({                                     // Update in response handler: you have the results, so you should re-render here
    longitude: weatherDataCityCoordinateLongitude,
    latitude: weatherDataCityCoordinateLatitude,
    name: weatherDataCityName,
    country: weatherDataCityCountry,
    placeName: event.target.value,
    showDetails: true                                 // and you know here you have details, so include them in state
  });
}
...
inputHandleChange: function( event ) {
  if ( event.target.value.trim().length > 0 ) {
    // if we have a valid input, then we send off request
    var getWeatherRequest             = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ...
    getWeatherRequest.send();
  }
  this.setState({ showDetails :false });             // and we always hide the details while we wait for correct response
},
```